# node-cmd running ffmpeg commands fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

cmd package to run terminal commands so I can use ffmpeg installed on my machine but I am running into syntax trouble. Here is my command

```
let convert = () => {cmd.run('ffmpeg -re -i 
"https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 
44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 
6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast 
-g 30 -r 30 drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: \ text='Stack Overflow': 
fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \ boxborderw=5: x=
(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -f flv "rtmp://ingest-us-
east.a.switchboard.zone/live/moo-7hup2-mqxsa-b6kmd-gj2gq"');}
```

I am getting "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", I tried changing the single quotes into double quotes but ffmpeg doesn't like that apparently

Comment: The syntax highlighting already tells you something is not right... Double check all your quotes. You cannot nest single quotes within single quotes without escaping them, and same with double quotes.

Comment: I tried escaping the single quotes but still not working

Comment: try using 
text="Stack Overflow": 
not 
text='Stack Overflow':

Comment: No, it still brings up an error

Comment: Try to completly remove the quote around Stack Overflow.

Comment: No still no luck, I even tried taking out all the parts that includes single quotations and stilldon't work i.e 
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -i ACE.png -i logo2.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=40:40[ovrl1], [0:v][ovrl1] overlay=580:10:[v1];[2]scale=40:40[ovrl2], [v1][ovrl2] overlay=580:10:[v2];[v2] drawtext=fontfile=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: \text=VideoGami:fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/1.05" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv "rtmp://ingest-us-east.a.switchboard.zone/live/moo-7hup2-mqxsa-b6kmd-gj2gq"

Comment: It works when I directly write it onto the console